# Add context menu item to Windows Explorer's File context in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, contextmenu, windows-explorer

I'm building an UWP application in which I need to add some of it's features to Windows Explorer's File context, that is, when the user clicks some (or any) file or folder with the right button of the mouse, there will be a menu item with options provided by my application, much like the "Send to..." and "Open with..." options which exist by default on Windows. I also want to give the user the ability to disable the menu or some of it's options, so I would like to know if it's possible to dynamically add and remove options and the whole menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fileTypeAssociation to achieve this.
This links will help you do it.

[[UWP]How to add an item into Windows Explorer context menu?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d81ed0c7-a96a-4b47-a685-3f927fef9438/uwphow-to-add-an-item-into-windows-explorer-context-menu?forum=wpdevelop)

[Add options to the context menus of files that have a certain file type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#add)

[Handle File Activation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Hope this helps.

Thanks.